# What is the Tanger GR bus terminal destination?

Tags: buses, language-barrier, morocco, french-language

I would like to check buses from Tanger to Tetouan but I have one problem. I can't figure out whether it is Tanger MED or Tanger. The page I've found it is in French.

Here is the page: http://www.ctm.ma/horaires-et-tarifs/acheter-un-billet

You can find there departure destination either Tanger or Tanger GR so I suppose that Tanger GR should be Tanger MED but I have to be sure.

Could you give me an advice?

Comment: GR in French stands for "Gare Routière", or bus station..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tanger-Med is the Tangiers harbour. Tanger GR stands for `Gare Routière` which is french for Central Bus Station. [It can be found here according to google maps.](https://goo.gl/maps/7Az5h) The other Tanger stop is apparently some other bus station in Tangiers, [according to this tripadvisor thread](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g293730-i9195-k6874715-Taxis_and_buses_in_between_Tangier_Tetouan_Chefchaouen-Morocco.html). It could very well be the CTM terminal in Tangiers. Indeed, the [Wikivoyage page on Tangier](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tangier) says:

> #### By Bus
>
> Tangier has two long distance bus stations. The first, at the CTM offices near the port, is the arrival point of most CTM buses. Some other CTM buses, and those from other companies, arrive at the station on Place Jamia el-Arabia.